# Report with Raw Data and Percentages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Given the following table:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mother](

```
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CaseNumberFK] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[AgeAtBirth] [tinyint] NULL,
[EthnicityFK] [int] NULL,
[EthnicityAdditionalFK] [int] NULL,
[EducationFK] [int] NULL
```

)

The Fields EthinicityFK and EducationFK have multiple values. Ethnicity can be {White, Black, Asian,Other} and Education is something like {GED, Some College, College}

The client is asking for a report like the table below.  I need to do this for bother Race and Education.

Mother’s Race

```
    N   %
    10   20 White
    10   20 African American/Black
    10   20 American Indian/Alaskan Native
    10   20 Asian
     0    0 Multi-racial
     0    0 Other
    10   20 No response
    50  100
```

Is this best way to go about this to create a SQL view and then just use a SELECT * query in my report?  Or is there a better way to do this withing the Report Designer itself?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to get started on a report to show this data.

I recommend you use the SSRS Business Intelligence Tools for Visual Studio.  The download is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313).

I recommend you start by creating a new report and using the SELECT * query as a dataset.

From there, you can make a matrix that can include this data easily.  Furthermore, you could create nice little pie charts and other useful visuals to give your report some color.

Here is a decent guide to get you started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167305(v=sql.105).aspx